# Bit Error Probability for 8PSK

Tags: digital-modulation

I'm trying to understand how to derive the BEP for 8PSK by geometrically looking at the decision regions.

Say I have this 8PSK signal set and the corresponding decision boundaries.

[image]

I assume that '000' is sent, and I want to calculate the BEP. So I have

$$P_b(e) = \frac{1}{3}(1 \times R_1 + 1 \times R_2 + 2 \times R_3 + 1 \times R_4 + 2 \times R_5 + 2 \times R_6 + 3 \times R_7)$$

Since \$R_1 = R_4\$, \$R_3 = R_5\$ and \$R_2 = R_7\$ by symmetry, the above can be simplified to

$$P_b(e) = \frac{2}{3}(R_1 + 2R_2 + 2R_3 + R_6)$$

Then we have

$$R_1 + R_2 + R_3 + R_6 = P\Big(n > d_1sin\frac{\pi}{8}\Big)\tag{1}$$

and

$$R_2 + R_3 = P\Big(n_0 > d_1sin\frac{3\pi}{8}\Big) \times P\Big(n_1 < d_1sin\frac{\pi}{8}\Big)\tag{2}$$

I'm having a hard time visualizing and understanding how \$(1)\$ and \$(2)\$ are obtained.

I understand that \$n\$ is the noise vector, and \$n_0\$ and \$n_1\$ are the horizontal and vertical components of the noise vector, and we are trying to find out how far \$n\$ or \$n_0\$ and \$n_1\$ will go to "push" the signal into the wrong decision region.

I've seen the following from this [website](http://iwct.sjtu.edu.cn/Personal/mxtao/course_comm/comm_ch08_digmod_en.pdf), and it seems to explain \$(1)\$, that is, the noise vector \$n\$ "pushes" the signal past the decision line (DL) into the wrong decision regions \$R_1 + R_2 + R_3 + R_6\$.

But what about \$(2)\$? I don't know why we have \$sin\frac{3\pi}{8}\$ and \$sin\frac{\pi}{8}\$.

[image]

Also, is the noise vector always perpendicular to the decision boundaries?

Answer (score 1):

Equations (1) and (2) don't appear to be correct, or at least they are incomplete.  The received signal will be a 2 dimensional gaussian centered on the (000) signal point or (x = 1, y = 0).  That is:

[image]

So to compute the error probability, you integrate f(x,y) over the regions you describe above.

The noise vector, n, is a gaussian random vector and is not generally normal to the decision boundaries.